# Two cards are drawn from a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards without replacement.The first card is a face card and the second card is a diamond.

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn from a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards without replacement. What is the probability of when The first card is a face card and the second card is a diamond.

I am confused because I thought it is $\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{13}{51}$ but it is not that simple.
There are 3 diamond face cards, so should the equation be $\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{10}{51}$?

Comment: Hint: split into two cases.  Case $1$ in which the first face is not a diamond and Case $2$ in which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of drawing a face card that is not a diamond in the first turn is 9/52.
In this case, the probability of finding a diamond in the second draw is 13/51.

The probability of drawing a diamond face card in the first turn is 3/52.
In this case, the probability of finding a diamond in the second draw is 12/51, because one of the diamonds has already been drawn.

Given that the cases considered are mutually exclusive, we get that the full probability is

$$p = \frac{9}{52}\frac{13}{51}+\frac{3}{52}\frac{12}{51} = \frac{9(13+4)}{52\cdot 51} = \frac{9\cdot 17}{51\cdot 52}.$$